# configure workitemhandler to send email in JBPM 7

Tags: java, jbpm

below is the work item handler currently we have to send email in JBPM 7.32.

But we are getting error `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to send email`".

```
new org.jbpm.process.workitem.email.EmailWorkItemHandler("smtp.gmail.com", "465", 
                                                       "ax@gmail.com", "x@gmail.com",true)
```

Could you please help.

Below is the sample workflow we have , to just send an email.

[image]

below is the settings where we have this e-mail work item handler.

[image]

Comment: can you provide more details? where are you calling the  work item handler ?

Comment: sorry but it is still not clear, where do you put this line of code `new org.jbpm.process.workitem.email.EmailWorkItemHandler("smtp.gmail.com", "465", "ax@gmail.com", "x@gmail.com",true)` 
?

Comment: did you add the work item handler of Email manually?

Comment: Sorry for the delay accepting the answers of my previous questions. I have acccepted now.

Comment: Yeah the e-mail handler its automatically got added ,later we have modified the contents ("smtp.gmail.com", "465", "ax@gmail.com", "x@gmail.com",true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Delete the Email task from your BPMN web Design (process graphic)
2. Delete the Email from Work Item Handlers
3. go to Settings/Service Tasks and Install Email (if it is installed, unistall it and click on install)
4. fill the form with required parameters:
   **host** : smtp server host name 
   **port** : smtp server port number
   **username** : account to be used when login to SMTP server (the email address)
   **password** : account's password to be used when login to SMTP server
5. if you provide all this informations, the Work Item Handler will be generated automatically ( you can check it in Settings/Deployments/ work Item Handlers), **DON'T EDIT IT** !
6. Go back to your Process, and insert again the email task as in the following screen shot
   [image]
7. Select your Email task, go to the Diagram properties (on the right), and click on Assignments.
   [image]
8. You can now assign global variables or constants to each attribute (Body,From,Subject,To) 
   **From** : valid email address
   **To** : valid email address of the recipients (to specify multiple addresses separate them with semicolon ';')
   **Subject** : email subject
   **Body** : email body (can include html)

Comment: At 4th point, what could be hostname and port number if we want to use the Gmail Account

Comment: the same that you putted in your parameters while calling the old work item handler: **hostname**: smtp.gmail.com  and **port** : 465

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay as i am working on other projects as well. I am still getting the error Unable to send e-mail

Comment: Hi, it seems not working with g-mail, due to security issues. i have tried with rediffmail its working. thank you for your support and valuable time.

Comment: How to send email without authentication. My SMTP server does not have any authentication.