# How do I define SMTP for sending mail in jBPM 7?

Tags: jbpm

I'm evaluating jBPM 7 and have it running locally. I have a Process and I'm trying to add a very simple email notification. I can see the email script task, but it only has variables for Body, From, Subject and To.

How do I actually define the SMTP server that will send the mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To configure the email service task take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60492109/5988526)

to add other variables you can click on the button **Add** and define your variables
[image]

The input variables that you can use are :

- From
- To
- Reply-To
- Cc
- Bcc
- Body
- Template
- Subject
- Attachments

you can find [here](https://github.com/kiegroup/jbpm/blob/master/jbpm-workitems/jbpm-workitems-email/src/main/java/org/jbpm/process/workitem/email/EmailWorkItemHandler.java) the source code of the `EmailWorkItemHandler`. If you want to add other variables that are not declared there, you can create your own Work Item Handler (a customized task)

Comment: Thank you, these nice to know, but I was specifically asking of the SMTP and its credentials, not the contents of the message that will be sent.

Comment: take a look at the first link I've shared, it describes how to configure the SMTP

Comment: or you can use WorkItemHandler to have your own Task, in which you can handle everything you want