# Could not find work item handler for Email

Tags: drools, jbpm

I am trying to achieve email alert from bpm flow in drools.

Below are the steps I have taken

**Step 1 :** Added email task in bpm flow and configured

[image]

**Step 2 :** Configured work item handlers

```
new org.jbpm.process.workitem.email.EmailWorkItemHandler("smtp.gmail.com","587","hello@gmail.com","xseregrgr","true")
```

[image]

**Step3 :** Standalone.xml configuration file changes

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:3.0">
      <mail-session name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default">
          <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp" username="hello@gmail.com" password="xyz" tls="true"/>           
      </mail-session>
</subsystem>

<outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
      <remote-destination host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587"/>
</outbound-socket-binding>
```

Post all this during testing , we received  **Could not find work item handler for Email**

Anything got missed. Please let me know.

Comment: Please accept my answer as it seems it is correct answer and solves your question. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the WorkItem Definition. You can give it name like "Gmail email client send" and should look something like this:

```
[
    [
        "name" : "Email",
        "displayName" : "Gmail email client send",
        "category" : "jbpm-workitems-email",
        "description" : "",
        "defaultHandler" : "mvel: new org.jbpm.process.workitem.email.EmailWorkItemHandler()",
        "documentation" : "jbpm-workitems-email/index.html",

        "parameters" : [
                            "Reply-To" : new StringDataType()
            ,"Cc" : new StringDataType()
            ,"Bcc" : new StringDataType()
            ,"From" : new StringDataType()
            ,"To" : new StringDataType()
            ,"Body" : new StringDataType()
            ,"Attachments" : new StringDataType()
            ,"Subject" : new StringDataType()
            ,"Debug" : new StringDataType()
            ,"Template" : new StringDataType()

        ],
        "mavenDependencies" : [
                             "org.jbpm:jbpm-workitems-email:7.34.0.Final"

        ],
        "icon" : "Email.png"

    ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60485774/configure-workitemhandler-to-send-email-in-jbpm-7) works fine with the latest JBPM 7.25 version. Here some more details about the signle steps.

It's important that you *delete everything* that you added so far related to the email sending (e.g. Service Worker, Deployment configs, EMail send tasks in process model). This could be outdated or influence the configuration negative.

Start by open your "Project Settings" in Business Central and click "Install" for the "Email" Service Task.

[image]

Provide your EMail-Provider Configuration (Host, Port, User Name, Password). E.g. for Gmail this can be found [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en).
*Warning: Please note that for Gmail you need to active the access for "Less secure apps" [here](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)* to connect to the SMTP Server.

[image]

With the provided Information JBPM generates the required WorkItemHandler configuration (you need to refresh the page to see it). If you need to, you can update values here later on when you need to change the Mail-Provider configuration.
[image]

Next we build a new Business Process Model and add the required Email task.
[image]

Finally we can configure the Email task with the information for sending the email (e.g. From, To, Subject, Body)
[image]

That's all. Now you can deploy and run the Process.

Answer (score 0):

go to Settings/Service Tasks and Install Email

Comment: I have followed your post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60485774/configure-workitemhandler-to-send-email-in-jbpm-7       but still the same issue persists. do i have to make any changes in standalone.xml

Comment: do i have to install service task as well

Comment: don't touch the standalone.xml ,  it is not recommended to do so.  just follow the steps in the post and it should work and you don't have to install  "service task" , it is an other workitem, install only email

Comment: {
 "start-process": {
  "processId": "test123.emal"
 }
}


  I have followed all your steps . I am hitting via API.                                                                                                                    
  In response i am getting this                                                         


{
  "type" : "FAILURE",
  "msg" : "Error calling container test123: [test123.emal:1 - Email:3] -- Could not find work item handler for Email",
  "result" : null
}

Comment: any sample project can be shared

Comment: delete everything related to the email task and start over, reset your standalone.xml and delete the Configured work item handlers, and uninstall email, just try again from the beginning as described in the other answer, it should work, it contains all details

Comment: still same issue. Anything needs to be checked or added while deploying in kie-server.